# What is the logic of the Shushan Purim davening and brachot?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, purim, shushan-purim

Why is it that on Shushan Purim, when we do not say tachanun, we do not add the Purim paragraph to the amida or to the birchat hamazon?  Why do the two not go together?

Comment: We skip Tachanun on many days when we don't add anything special to prayers.

Comment: Yes.  Some skip tachanu, and some skip it quite often, for minor reasons.  But there is a paragraph for Purim and we are skipping tachanun for an aspect of Purim (Shushan Purim).

Comment: @YehudaW the point Isaac is making is that you shouldn't expect that we add something to shmoneh esrei just because we skip tachanun. It's no longer Purim so we don't add that paragraph.

Comment: Should you say Yaaleh veYavo on Pesach Sheni?

Comment: @double-aa  I would think saying yaaleh on Pesach Sheni is logical if Pesach Sheni it is being observed, and not logical if it is not being observed.  Hmm.  By that logic we would only make the changes on Sushan Purim in a walled city.  But we do not do that.  We omit Tachanun on Sushan P everywhere.  OTOH, only some congregations omit Tachanun on Pesach Sheni, per Reb Scroll.  So, perhaps it is even less real today, even tho of biblical origin.

Comment: @YehudaW SHouldn't those congs that omit tachanun on PSheni say Yaaleh veYavo as well?